# mvc exclude css from bundle in partial

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

Sorry, I'm complete noob in mvc and I need to exclude one of the main StyleBundle's from my view:

`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));`

which is rendering in _Layout.cshtml from one of my view pages. View page is a photo gallery. It has its own css, which conflicts with that core *site.css*. I've already tried to insert:

`@{BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("~/Content/css");}` or `@{BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("site.css");}`

to my photo gallery page, but in first case i got nothing, and in second case mvc completely ignores **all bundles** exept my photogallery css.

Is there any simple way to deal with it except using different _*Layout.cshtml*?

Comment: While it may not be trivial, a method I use is to have a reset css file included after the main site.css and before the new css file that cancels out the site.css properties you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any simple way to deal with it except using different _Layout.cshtml?

No, once you've included a bundle, it will be rendered in the markup.

You certainly don't want to modify the `IgnoreList` as this is a global property and changing it will effect all the other pages in your application.